# Study the uniform convergence of the functional series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \sin(nx)}{\sqrt n+x^2} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Study the uniform convergence of the functional series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \sin(nx)}{\sqrt n+x^2} $$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$

I thought of using the Abel theorem since the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n +x^2}$ converges by Leibniz test, but can I say that  $\{\sin(nx)\}$ is monotone?

Or should I use another criterion?

**UPDATE**

I think I got it now.
I should use the Dirihle's test.

The finite series $$\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \sin(ix)$$  is bounded because $$|\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \sin(ix) |= |\sum_{i=0}^n \sin(ix+\frac{\pi x}{2})|= |\frac{\sin((\frac{n+1}2)(x+\frac{\pi}2))\sin((\frac{n}2)(x+\frac{\pi}2))}{\sin(\frac x2+\frac \pi4)}| \le \frac 1{|\sin(\frac x2+\frac \pi4)|}$$
And the sequence $\{\frac 1{\sqrt n +x^2}\}$ is a zero sequence monotonically decreasing . Now from the Dirihle's Test the series converges uniformly

Comment: The question is incomplete, since you don't tell us what is the domain of your functions.

Comment: There is a general freedom of speech, but $\sin(nx)$ is definitely not monotone.